# Anchoring a QGraphicsView to the corner of the screen

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I have a `QGraphicsView` that renders my game. This view fills the entire screen at all times. In the top right I have another `QGraphicsView` which I'm using as a mini-map; it sits over the game view. I want this mini-map to be anchored to the top right of the screen, always maintaining its size. This code almost works, except that the left side of the mini-map never changes (which is [to be expected](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qrect.html#setRight)).

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    mainWindow->graphicsView->resize(event->size().width(), event->size().height());
    QRect newRect(mainWindow->miniMapGraphicsView->geometry());
    newRect.setRight(event->size().width() - 20);
    mainWindow->miniMapGraphicsView->setGeometry(newRect);
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to position widgets in a certain way, layouts are usually the best way to do it.

Add a `QFormLayout` to your `graphicsView` and set its `layoutDirection` to `Qt::RightToLeft`. Then add your `miniMapGraphicsView` to the layout. Editing the properties of the mini map, set its horizontal and vertical `sizePolicy` to `Fixed` and set its `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` to the dimensions you would like it to be.

An alternative would be to use a `QGridLayout` and use horizontal and vertical spacers to push the mini map to any corner of the view.

**NOTE:** Layouts have margins set by default so if you want your widgets to align snugly at the edges, zero them out.

Comment: Does Designer support adding a `QFormLayout` to a `QGraphicsView`? When I try to add the layout, it gets added as a child of the `centralWidget` instead, and the views are sitting next to each other instead of one sitting on top of the other.

Comment: The designer does not seem to support that, which is unfortunate.